# Programmatically Edit a Protected microsoft Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I want to programmatically change the values of Drop Down Entries in a protected XLS . There are some 1000+ entries with value set to TBD and these entries are not in a sequence . Doing a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (replace) throws error that it is password protected sheet . Changing drop-down entry value manually works though .

Comment: do you need to keep it in xls format? Can you move it to an xlsx format and start from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the password,you can unprotect the sheet, chnage the cell and protect it again. You can evem record a macro like this. If you need the same file extension you can run it from a different workbook,alternatively. Again, this can be recorded.